# Block content with popup

Tags: plugins

I have a little hard problem since 2 days,
First of all I have a Wordpress site with privet content,
I made a privet page with a PDF visible only for subscribers, I made the subscribe with no password and if an user is already subscribed he can only fill a form with his email and he can visit the page,
I need to make a popup appears when a visitor click the bouton of visiting that pdf with login if he is a subscriber and inscription if he is new.
Any Ideas for that please ?
ThanksThanks

Comment: A popup might stop some users, but anyone with technical knowledge can bypass it - you are better to use server level protection - load the basic page, load the form, get the user to submit the form, if all good - load the rest of the page - via AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my question wasn't clear so I made some changes, Thanks